# Javascript - Assign respective values between range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have the following map:

```
const values = {
  1: 100,
  2: 300,
  3: 120,
}
```

and function, that generates HSL colors

```
export const generateHSLColor = (hue, saturation, lightness) => {
  return "hsl(" + hue + "," + saturation + "%," + lightness + "%)";
};
```

Now, I want to get HSL colors where **hue = 211, saturation = 100, and lightness is dynamic**.

The lightness has to be between **[50, 95]**, and depends of the map values.

For the following map:

```
{
  1: 100
}
```

**as 100 is the unique value, its lightness will be the lowest in the interval** (**[50, 95]**), which is **50**.

In other words, the total count of values has the lowest lightness.

I need an algorithm to correctly associate the lightness, to the values.

So, for the original map "values", the total count is 100 + 300 + 120, which lighness is 50.

How can I get the lightness values between the range **[50, 95]** for 100, 300 and 120?

"Bigger values of the map, correspond to a lower lightness in the range"

```
 function getColor(value) { 
    // Hue
    const hue = 211;

    // Saturation
    const saturation = 100;

    // Dynamic Lightness
    const minLightness = 50;
    const maxLightness = 95;
    // const lightness = ?; has to be between the range

    return generateHSLColor(hue, saturation, minLightness);
  }


   getColor(values[1]); // Color for 100
   getColor(values[2]); // Color for 300 
   getColor(values[3]); // Color for 120
```

Comment: so, like, what is the logic behind the choices? what i mean is: when does `100 + 300 + 120` somehow turn to `50`?

Comment: @TheBombSquad the total count of values has the lowest lightness, 50. And 0 has the greatest, 95. Then, the real values of the map have to get their respective lightness inside that range.

Comment: Does it matter at all that you plan to use the value as "lightness"?  The HSL stuff seems like just a distraction in this question.  The goal is to produce a number in the rang [50, 95] based on an an object with integer keys and values.  Describe the rules of that function in as much detail as you can. Use several example input objects and several results and explain why the result follows from the input.

Comment: @Raul i posted an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, according to what you told me

1. I'm inferring that it has to read the object `values` to get the sum of all its values
2. If the object `values` ever changes, the results for each value would be different

```js
let values = {1: 100,  2: 300,  3: 120}
function generateHSLColor (hue, saturation, lightness) {
  return "hsl(" + hue + "," + saturation + "%," + lightness + "%)";
}
function getColor(obj,num) {
  let min=50, max=95, diff=max-min;
  let sum=Object.values(obj).reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
  var dynamicNumber=Math.round(min+(diff-((num/sum)*diff)));
  return generateHSLColor(211, 100, dynamicNumber);
}

//examples using object values
Object.values(values).forEach(a=>{
  console.log(getColor(values,a))
})
//
console.log("min and max examples")
//
//minimum example
let minimum=0
console.log(getColor(values,minimum))
//maximum example
let maximum=Object.values(values).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
console.log(getColor(values,maximum))

/*
now to expand what dynamicNumber is
num is used in relative to the sum, then multiplied by the range(called diff)
this value is used to subtract from the range(since 0 is supposed to be highest and the sum to be the lowest)
this resultant number is then rounded(because I don't think you asked for decimal points)
did I do it right?
*/
```

Comment: const lightness =
          maxLightness - (num * lightnessDiff) / sum;  // Simplified formula that produces same result! THX!!!!

Comment: interesting way of doing it :D